# How do I move a view around the DOM with angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I move an element to different places in the DOM with angular js?

I have a list of elements like so

```
<ul id="list" ng-controller="ListController">
    <li ng-controller="ItemController"><div>content</div></li>
    <li ng-controller="ItemController"><div>content</div></li>
    <li ng-controller="ItemController"><div>content</div></li>
    <li ng-controller="ItemController">
        <div>content</div>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is moving the #overlay from place to place within the list without having to have a hidden duplicate in every item that I flag hidden/unhidden.

If this was jquery I could just do something like this:

```
$("#overlay").appendTo("#list li:first-child");
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in angular?

Comment: AngularJS is approaching UI from the model-focused angle. This means that you usually manipulate your model and let AngularJS figure out how to render things. Could you please elaborate a bit on your use case, from the functional point of view, so one could propose a solution that fits nicely into the AngularJS-way?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically the use case is that I have a long stream of social data and actions such as "tweet, share, pin" are hidden in an overlay triggered by a click or swipe within that item. The overlay should only be on one social stream item at a time.

At the moment I have this "overlay" div inside of the ng-repeat call and I simply set hidden-true or hidden-false. the problem is I'm broadcasting a "closeOverlay" call to 50 - 100 items in case another one is open and that seems overboard. Managing an overlay separately and appending it as necessary seems like a better choice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to your clarifications I can understand that you've got a list of items. You would like to be able to select one item in this list (swipe but potentially other events as well) and then display an additional DOM element (div) for a selected item. If the other item was selected it should be un-selected - this way only one item should have an additional div displayed.

If the above understanding is correct, then you could solve this with the simple ng-repeat and ng-show directives like this:

```
<ul ng-controller="ListController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div ng-click="open(item)">{{item.content}}</div>
        <div ng-show="isOpen(item)">overlay: tweet, share, pin</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where the code in the controller would be (showing a fragment of it only):

```
$scope.open = function(item){
    if ($scope.isOpen(item)){
        $scope.opened = undefined;
    } else {
        $scope.opened = item;
    }        
};

$scope.isOpen = function(item){
    return $scope.opened === item;
};
```

Here is the complete jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/65Cxv/7/

If you are concerned about having too many DOM elements you could achieve the same using ng-switch directive:

```
<ul ng-controller="ListController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div ng-click="open(item)">{{item.content}}</div>
        <ng-switch on="isOpen(item)">
            <div ng-switch-when="true">overlay: tweet, share, pin</div>
        </ng-switch>        
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/bBtH3/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I had a feeling something in this direction might make more sense but this has clarified some things for me. I will play around with a bit more and try integrating one of the methods

Comment: Does `ng-switch` cache a previously generated DOM? If not, the second approach still has a downside of creating DOM elements each time `ng-switch.on` expression changes. Right?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda no I don't believe there to be any caching. It's good in the sense that it fully removes the unused DOM elements though which I've found it really handy in larger JS apps where you don't want to be keeping a lot of ununsed DOM elements hanging around with "display:none" in css.

Comment: This is why there are both ngShow and ngSwitch options described - one can choose to keep DOM nodes around or not.

Answer (score 4):

As an exercise for the reader (me), I wanted to try a custom directive to accomplish this.  Here is what I came up with (after many failed attempts):

```
<ul ng-controller="ListController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div singleton-overlay>{{item.content}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

A service is required to store the element that currently has the overlay, if any.  (I decided against using the controller for this, since I think a 'service + directive' would make for a more reusable component than a 'controller + directive'.)

```
service('singletonOverlayService', function() {
    this.overlayElement = undefined;
})
```

And the directive:

```
directive('singletonOverlay', function(singletonOverlayService) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', moveOrToggleOverlay);

            function moveOrToggleOverlay() {
                if (singletonOverlayService.overlayElement === element) {
                    angular.element(element.children()).remove();
                    singletonOverlayService.overlayElement = undefined;
                } else {
                    if (singletonOverlayService.overlayElement != undefined) {
                        // this is a bit odd... modifying DOM elsewhere
                        angular.element(singletonOverlayService.overlayElement.children()).remove();
                    }
                    element.append('<div>overlay: tweet, share, pin</div>')
                    singletonOverlayService.overlayElement = element;
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/ya4De/

I think the implementation is a bit unconventional, though... the directive not only modifies the DOM associated with its own element, but it may also modify the DOM associated with the element that currently has the overlay.

I tried setting up $watches on scope and having the singleton store and modify scope objects, but I couldn't get the $watches to fire when I changed the scope from inside the moveOrToggleOverlay function.

Comment: Interesting read. I'm still playing with this and I appreciate different approaches to the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: In this approach, how does one change the content within the singletonOverlay based on which element what clicked/hovered upon?

Comment: Basically how does one pass some JS object from the scope of the "target element" to the singletonOverlay?

Comment: @Saurabh, inside moveOrToggleOverlay(), use whatever jqLite (or jQuery if you included it) methods you want to examine the clicked element and then you can append() whatever is appropriate to the DOM for that element.  Since this directive does not create an isolate scope, all scope properties in the ng-repeat child scope are available to the directive's link function.  So you shouldn't have to pass anything.