# AngularJS sort DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an usual use case.  I have a CMS that is providing partial data with a web service supplementing that data to complete the whole.  What works well with jQuery is to dump all of the partial data in to a holding area and when the web service responds, fill in the rest of the data and move it to the proper location.

I'm aware that this is similar to [How do I move a view around the DOM with angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428570/how-do-i-move-a-view-around-the-dom-with-angular-js) but I think it's a different use case and I'm not seeing the answer.

Basically, 90% of the DOM is loaded up front with what Angular can consider static data.  However, we don't know where things belong until the web service responds.  How do we 'sort' the DOM after the service responds?  There are a finite number of LIs - the web service is a state of those LIs, not a tool used to iterate over and create them.

My DOM looks something like:

```
<ul id="good">
</ul>

<ul id="bad">
</ul>

<ul id="temporary">
    <li id="bob"><p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</p> DOB {{bob.dob}}</li>
    <li id="susan"><div>Roses are red violets are blue</div>Name: Susan, DOB: {{susan.dob}}</li>
    <li id="paul">Name: Paul, DOB: {{paul.dob}}</li>
<ul>
```

I know that its as easy as ng-repeat on each UL if everything came from the service but much of the template is static, but yet each LI is different, and the data to create the static-but-different content is not available at the web service.  That's just how it is.  It can't be changed.

The web service will respond with something like:

```
{
   "good": [{
      "id": "paul",
      "dob": "01/01/2014"
   }, {
      "id": "susan",
      "dob": "05/01/2014"
  }],
  "bad": [{
     "id": "bob",
     "dob": "12/25/2013"
  }]
}
```

So, those in the "good" category need to move to the "good" UL, and those in the "bad" category need to move to the "bad" UL.  In jQuery this is just:

```
$("#bob").appendTo("#bad");
```

The DOM is much more complicated than the above, so the hope is to take a div by some identifier and move the entire thing to a different container.

The way we are currently doing it is by having every LI in every UL and using ng-if to show/hide it based on category, but that seems like a shotgun approach and something more elegant would be useful.

Is this even possible?  We cant just update a model, because the model does not contain enough information to create the view.

Comment: Its very possible with the magic of `ng-repeat`, but my concern with your question lies here: "We cant just update a model, because the model does not contain enough information to create the view.". Why? The data does exist to render the view, why can't it live in the model?

Comment: What I mean is that there are maybe one or two dynamic pieces, but 50 static ones.  So, we need to take the LI as-is including all of the static data (which is different for each LI) and move it somewhere else, then fill it in.  Or vice versa.  The order shouldn't matter.  I'll update the DOM - i made it look too similar from LI to LI and it's not like that.

Comment: $scope.bad = [{id: "bob"}, {id: "susan"}] with ng-repeat="people in bad" won't work because the LI itself needs to move.  if we did ng-repeat, we'd wind up having an ENORMOUS DOM written in multiple places when itll only ever live in one, and we'd like to avoid that since the LIs are being sent to the browser, not rendered client-side by angular.  If we can populate them and sort them in to a specifiable container while keeping the inner DOM, we're in business.

Comment: sorry, it sounds like you have a bad design problem. The model is the model, period. You are mixing paradigms and tripping on it. You need to have the server send you data, not html. You need to have templating for statics, not hacks. You need to let angular handle the model and rendering, not try and shoehorn jQuery hacks into it. Moving the dom elements around is something you should do with ng-repeat. The whole idea of angular is to never have to perform the exact type of task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What you are talking about is using dom manipulation as a means managing the model. You can't do it in angular, and you shouldn't do it anyway.

Comment: that's what i was wondering...  just not how its done.  we're running in to some items while transitioning from jquery to angular that are like this.  thanks for the help.

Comment: its a big transition. Good luck :) I moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, it sounds like you have a bad design problem. The model is the model, period. You are mixing paradigms and tripping on it. You need to have the server send you data, not html. You need to have templating for statics, not hacks. You need to let angular handle the model and rendering, not try and shoehorn jQuery hacks into it. Moving the dom elements around is something you should do with ng-repeat. The whole idea of angular is to never have to perform the exact type of task you are trying to accomplish.